# Blazor server searchbar

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

i want to have a search bar in my blazor app that has the same style and functionality as the one in amazon [image]

in the way that the person has to choose a filter and then type something in the search bar then click search.how can i achieve that

i have tried this code "

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span id="search_concept">All</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#contains">Example 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#its_equal">Example 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#greather_than">Example 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#less_than">Example 4</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#all">All</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

" since this requires js and i dont want to use js the filtering option doesnt open

Comment: You need to be clearer on the js constraint - are you completely forbidden from using js for security purpose? In that case you cannot use blazor either since blazor requires js files. It appears that you are using bootstrap for dropdown filter  - the dropdown won't work unless you use bootstrap's js.